# How to run shadow jar with a gradle task?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, shadowjar

I want to run my app after building it with the shadow jar plugin.

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.3.21"
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "5.0.0"
}

group 'org.example.java'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:1.1.3"
}
```

I also have a global init.gradle:

```
gradle.projectsLoaded {
    rootProject.allprojects {
        buildDir = "/Users/User/Builds/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
    }
}
```

So now the fat jar can be built to my global build directory with the shadowJar task. But I want to be able to run and build it with just one run configuration in IntelliJ. How do I do that?

Maybe there is another way to let gradle redirect all my output to a global build directory. I don't want to configure each IntelliJ project with the same output path manually. Suggestions are welcome.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not touch the `buildDir` property for achieving what you want.

Instead, you should create a `JavaExec` task that will start the application from the shadow jar.
If you want that execution to be at a different place than the default location of the generated jar, you should either change the output of the shadow task itself, and only *that* output or make your execution task depend on a copy task that would move the shadow jar around.

Something like:

```
shadowJar {
    destinationDir = "/Users/User/Builds/${rootProject.name}/${project.name}"
}

task runApp(type: JavaExec) {
    main = "your.main.Class
    classpath = shadowJar.archiveFile // use archivePath before Gradle 5.1
}
```

Comment: Thx :) But what if I want all output to be in a build directory outside of my projects (also for non-shadow projects)

Comment: Then what you did with the `buildDir` was one solution. And means the snippet above can forget about the `shadowJar` task configuration.

Comment: Now use `getDestinationDirectory()` as `destinationDir` is deprecated.

Comment: To be exact: `getDestinationDirectory().set(new File(projectDir, "./build/my_folder"));`